# jQuery gentle scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

due to the nature of my site, I often have to link to anchors listed within a page, rather than just to the page itself. An example can be found here: http://www.unknowntales.net/chapter/route/choice/#chapter3

What I'm looking for is some jQuery code which I can use to make the page slowly scroll down to the anchor, rather than jumping to it directly.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

assuming your html is:

```
<a href="#someid">click me</a>
<h1 id="someid">some heading<h1>
```

this should work

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset - 100 }, 500);
});
```

**Edit: What Liam said (see comment below)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work properly. It works fine for pages where the link and the anchor are on the same page, but it prevents all links from working at all.

Another point to note is that most of the time, the link to the anchor will be coming from another page, so it'll need to be able to grab the # from the url.

Thank you.

Comment: well for the first part, add a class to the link that denotes it as being "same page" then use `$('a.myclass')` as your selector.

For the second part, i wouldnt do that. sounds like bad usability

Comment: Use `$('a[href^="#"]')` to only select links that go to anchors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is something i put together a while back.

```
    $('a', this)
    .each(function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^\s/, '').replace(/\s$/, '');
        var parts = url.split("#", 2);
        var anchors = $("#" + parts[1] + ", a[name='" + parts[1] + "']");
        if (anchors.length > 0) {
            $(this).click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('html, body')
                .animate({
                    scrollTop: $(anchors.get(0)).offset().top
                }, {
                    duration: 1500,
                    specialEasing: {
                        scrollTop: 'easeOutQuint'
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

If i edited this again I would replace my anchor filtering with $('a[href^="#"]') liam's selector.